# Bind hasPendingChanges() to View-Model

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to use the `hasPendingChanges()` method from v2 ODataModel in my view. Therefore I want to set a property named `detailView>/pendingChnages` in my view-model.
Is there a event in v2 ODataModel or in binding (element / context-binding) for every change to check the hasPendingChanges-method in v2 ODataModel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I Just found a solution for my requirement. I could remember a video I've watched recently: https://youtu.be/-bs-RBG7f5Q?t=2116

For the solution I register a change-Event for a `sap.ui.model.Binding`.

```
var oCtx = this.getView().getBindingContext();
var oBinding = new sap.ui.model.Binding(this.getView().getModel(), oCtx.getPath(), oCtx);
oBinding.attachChange(function(){
    this.getView().getModel("detailView").setProperty("/pendingChanges", this.getModel().hasPendingChanges());
}.bind(this));
```